# get and set the value from asp.net customized checkbox from server side

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox

This is my `html` code

```css
.checkboxFour {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px 90px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.checkboxFour label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #26ca28;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="checkboxFour">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name="" />
    <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bpja2nw1/)

How can I get and set this checkbox value from server side ?
Using HiddenField or something ?

Comment: are you using ASP.Net Web Forms or MVC?

Comment: asp.net web Forms !

Comment: Any specific reason to not use ASP Web Controls? In this case assp:CheckBox?

Comment: can I set asp:CheckBox's style like I shown ?

Comment: Your style is purely CSS based so yes. You can style web controls the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name="" />

string cbvalue = checkboxFourInput.Value;//get
checkboxFourInput.Value = val;//set
```

add `runat="server"` attribute to get/set the value from server side. put it inside `form` tag having `runat="server"` attribute

Comment: the check box doesn't work if i add `runat="server"` attribute !

Comment: did you put it inside form tag having runat="server" attribute?

Comment: i put it inside `contentPlaceHolder` having `runat="server"` attribute !

Comment: does the master page have a form tag?

Comment: yes , mainMaster page has form tag with `runat=server`

Comment: Is the contentPlaceHolder in master page inside form tag?

Comment: Yes , contentPlaceHolder is in master page inside form tag !

Comment: I can't check it, the checkbox color doesn't changed if I add `runat="server"` tag inside !

Comment: Id of checkbox might be modified in HTML sent to browser. Please check if it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Create an ASPX page and add below code:

```
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="checkBox" value="MyTest" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbCheckBoxValue" runat="server" />
</div>

<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="Button_Click" />
```

In your code behind file add following code:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox.Checked)
            lbCheckBoxValue.Text = checkBox.Value;
        else
            lbCheckBoxValue.Text = "";

    }
```

Try above piece of code.